# How to create a python-style dictionary by data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking for a python-like dictionary structure in R to replace values in a large dataset (>100 MB) and I think data.table package can help me do this. However, I cannot find out an easy way to solve the problem.

For example, I have two data.table:

Table A:

```
   V1 V2
1:  A  B
2:  C  D
3:  C  D
4:  B  C
5:  D  A
```

Table B:

```
   V3 V4
1:  A  1
2:  B  2
3:  C  3
4:  D  4
```

I want to use B as a dictionary to replace the values in A. So the result I want to get is:

Table R:

```
V5 V6
 1  2
 3  4
 3  4
 2  3
 4  1
```

What I did is:

```
c2=tB[tA[,list(V2)],list(V4)]
c1=tB[tA[,list(V1)],list(V4)]
```

Although I specified j=list(V4), it still returned me with the values of V3. I don't know why.

c2:

```
   V3 V4
1:  B  2
2:  D  4
3:  D  4
4:  C  3
5:  A  1
```

c1:

```
   V3 V4
1:  A  1
2:  C  3
3:  C  3
4:  B  2
5:  D  4
```

Finally, I combined the two `V4` columns and got the result I want.

But I think there should be a much easier way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative way:

```
setkey(B, V3)
for (i in seq_len(length(A))) {
    thisA = A[[i]]
    set(A, j=i, value=B[thisA]$V4)
}
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  2
# 2:  3  4
# 3:  3  4
# 4:  2  3
# 5:  4  1
```

Since `thisA` is character column, we don't need the `J()` (for convenience). Here, `A`'s columns are replaced by reference, and is therefore also memory efficient. But if you don't want to replace `A`, then you can just use `cA <- copy(A)` and replace `cA`'s columns.

---

Alternatively, using `:=`:

```
A[, names(A) := lapply(.SD, function(x) B[J(x)]$V4)]
# or
ans = copy(A)[, names(A) := lapply(.SD, function(x) B[J(x)]$V4)]
```

(Following user2923419's comment): You can drop the `J()` if the lookup is a single column of type character (just for convenience).

---

In [1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), when `j` is a single column, it returns a vector (based on user request). So, it's a bit more natural data.table syntax:

```
setkey(B, V3)
for (i in seq_len(length(A))) {
    thisA = A[[i]]
    set(A, j=i, value=B[thisA, V4])
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why B[A[,V1],V4] returned V3 and V4 rather than just V4 itself?

Comment: I'm guessing you're on `1.9.2`. The join columns are also returned by default in versions <= 1.9.2.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using. So can I specify which column to return within the []?

Comment: For the second method, it's better to wrap `x` in J(). If x is integer, it will be regarded as row numbers rather than keys.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how fast this is with big data, but `chmatch` is supposed to be fast.

```
tA[ , lapply(.SD,function(x) tB$V4[chmatch(x,tB$V3)])]

   V1 V2
1:  1  2
2:  3  4
3:  3  4
4:  2  3
5:  4  1
```

Comment: Well, after reading the description, I found out that chmatch will biuld the hash table every time it is called. That will be inefficient. fmatch looks better since it will reuse the has table.

Comment: yeah..it looks like @Arun's answer is much better